# excepcion ejecutando jar con maven java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/exec/ProcessDestroyer

Tags: java, maven

Estoy realizando un `.jar` con maven, apenas termino de crear el proyecto en *netbeans*, agrego mi clase `main` y quiero ejecutar:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/commons/exec/ProcessDestroyer  at
> java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)   at
> java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)   at
> java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)  at
> com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
> at
> org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
> at
> org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
> at
> com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
> at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)    at
> org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
> at
> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
> at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
> at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)   at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)    at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)   at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.commons.exec.ProcessDestroyer  at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)

aparentemente parece un problema con alguna clase que no encuentra,
aca mi archivo .POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.ve.ventas</groupId>
   <artifactId>ventas</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties> </project>
```

Answer (score 2):

La exception `NoClassDefFoundError` ocurre típicamente cuando no se encuentra (en tiempo de ejecución) una clase que está en un jar externo (y que sí se encontraba presente al tiempo de compilación)

Tu jar está -probablemente- bien, pero al ejecutar debes incluir los jars de los cuales dependen (y que no están en el classpath).

Algo así como

```
  java -cp apache_commons_exec_nnnn.jar -jar mijar.jar
```

También puedes decirle a tu maven (o a tu Netbeans) que al momento de armar tu jar empaquete los jars externos.

Comment: si amigo efectivamente ya esta resuelto, voy a colocar el nombre del jar, ya que no se encuentra informacion al respecto, gracias

Comment: Bien. Te recuerdo que cuando consideres que tus preguntas estén respondidas (por un participante o por tí mismo) conviene que aceptes la respuestas (o la respondas tu mismo) así no queda como que está esperando una respuesta. Si es de ayuda: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

solo hacia falta descargar el .jar, en tu archivo pom, agregar esta dependecia, *clean and build* y listo.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
 </dependency>
```